# Inverting matrix with an identity row

Tags: inverse

By identity row, I mean a row in a square matrix that that has 0s everywhere except for a 1 in the n-th column. When you invert an NxN matrix with an identity row, does the inverted matrix always preserve the number of zeros (N-1) for that specific identity row?

Answer (score 0):

The inverted matrix will have an identity row at the exact same position. Here is how you can know this. Write down a matrix equation with you matrix:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\\ \text{$i$-th row} \to \\ \,
\end{matrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
&& \vdots \\ \hline 
0&\cdots &1& \cdots&0\\ \hline
&& \vdots
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\vdots \\x_i \\\vdots
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\vdots \\ y_i \\ \vdots
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The $i$-th row written as isolated equation looks like $x_i=y_i$. Therefore, if we bring the matrix to the other side by inverting it, the $i$-th row must look the same to yield the same identity.